# FullCalendar week view 2 events at the same hour?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have this in callendar but I want to know how to make the second activity in the same hour overlap. I tried `overlap: false` and `eventOverlap: false` but none of them work.
[image]

This is the code I have

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaFourDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, 
                defaultView: "agendaWeek",
                firstDay: 1,
                allDaySlot: false,
                  minTime: "08:00",
                  maxTime: "24:00",
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                eventOverlap: true,
                slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
                slotEventOverlap: true,
                events: [
                    //event data
                ],
            });

        });
```

Comment: Your code works for me https://imagebin.ca/v/3Zab0CaRfrp3 with these events:             events: [{
                title: 'Event 1',
                start: '2017-09-07 10:00',
                end: '2017-09-07 12:00'
            }, {
                title: 'Event 2',
                start: '2017-09-07 11:00',
                end: '2017-09-07 12:00'
            }],

Answer (score 0):

[`eventOverlap`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) should work when dragging or resizing - but you are using `false`, which will **not** allow events to overlap.  You say you want to allow them to overlap, so you should be using `true`.

You can use [`slotEventOverlap`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/) for initial rendering of agenda events - again, use `true`, not `false`, to allow them to overlap.

Comment: Did what you say, still no results

Comment: I wrote what you sugested, it is the same